# How can I run a simple text to speech command?

Tags: text-to-speech

In Windows I can do these steps:

```
1. Open Notepad
2. Copy and Paste 

CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak"Hello."

3. Save it as xyz.vbs
4. Run it/Open it
```

It will then speak "Hello". Is there something like this in Ubuntu?

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech

Comment: yes you can, see the first answer in the above link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the [`espeak`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/espeak) [image: Install espeak] package. Then run in a terminal

```
espeak -v en "Hello"
```

---

To change the voice, please refer to the manpage. An excerpt from `man espeak`:

```
   --voices[=<language code>]
          Lists  the available voices. If =<language code> is present then only
          those voices which are suitable for that language are listed.

   -v <voice name>
          Use voice file of this name from espeak-data/voices
```

Comment: Can I change the voice ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Where is that requirement given in the question? And for this example he provided in Windows you'll need Visual Basic scripting and speech synthesis components installed.

Comment: Is there any option for female vooice?

Answer (score 8):

There is a link which will give detailed text to speech command line tools.

http://elinux.org/RPi_Text_to_Speech_%28Speech_Synthesis%29

The first speech package I tried was Festival. It worked fine and produces a voice like a rough sounding robot.

**Festival Text to Speech**

Install Festival with:

```
sudo apt-get install festival
```

Try out Festival with:

```
echo “Just what do you think you're doing, Dave?” | festival --tts
```

**Espeak Text to Speech**
Espeak is a more modern speech synthesis package than Festival. It sounds clearer but does wail a little. If you are making an alien or a RPi witch then it’s the one for you! Seriously it is a good allrounder with great customisation options.

Install Espeak with:

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
```

Test Espeak with: English female voice, emphasis on capitals (-k), speaking slowly (-s) using direct text:-

```
espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s150 "I've just picked up a fault in the AE35 unit"
```