# Audio broadcast a logfile

Tags: sound, log, streaming

I am looking for a way to "listen" to a logfile. This is what I am thinking of:

```
while tail -f logfile
    for every new line in the logfile 
    convert this line to an audio file
    stream the audio file
```

How would I go about building this? I am using 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Example for your question:

```
tail -f logfile  | espeak -v en
```

More Text to Speech (TTS) like `espeak` programs and if you are looking for making audio `.wav` file examples can be fount at:

1. [Natural Sounding Text to Speech?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech)
2. [How can I run a simple text to speech command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419341/how-can-i-run-a-simple-text-to-speech-command)

Comment: Great! And how do i stream this to for example an icecast server?

Comment: You could try something like this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network